# Stop FactoryGirl converting my strings to floats

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot, fabrication-gem

I have these factories setup:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
        factory :product do
                name { Faker::Commerce.product_name }
                price { Faker::Commerce.price }
                image { Faker::Internet.url }
        end

        factory :new_product, parent: :product do
                name nil
                price nil
                image nil
        end

        factory :string_product, parent: :product do
                price { Faker::Commerce.price.to_s }
        end
end
```

Why do I want to use :string_product? Well, although the price attribute is of datatype float at the database level, occasionally I want to build a Factory with all of the attributes as strings.

This is so I can build the factory and then run expectations against its attributes when they are passed into the params hash. (All params from the URL are strings)

However, in the rails console:

```
> FactoryGirl.build :string_product
=> #<Product:0x00000007279780 id: nil, name: "Sleek Plastic Hat", price: 43.54, image: "http://blick.name/moie", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

As you can see, `price` is still being saved as a string.

An experiment to attempt to see what's going on:

```
        ...
        factory :string_product, parent: :product do
                price { "WHY ARE YOU NOT A STRING?" }
        end
        ...
```

results in:

```
=> #<Product:0x000000077ddfa0 id: nil, name: "Awesome Steel Pants", price: 0.0, image: "http://rogahn.com/kavon", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

My string is now converted to the float `0.0`

How do I prevent this behavior? If I want to have one of my attributes as a string, especially when I'm only `build`ing it I should be allowed to. Is there a FactoryGirl configuration where I can stop this happening? Exactly the same thing happens with the `Fabrication` gem, so I'm guessing this is something to do with the model? My `Product` model is literally empty right now...no validations or anything, so how can that be? The only way FactoryGirl knows price is a float is because it has that datatype on the database level.

Anyway, this is really annoying, if someone could show me how to let me write strings to my Factory's attributes I would be very appreciative. I could use `.to_s` in the spec itself but I want to keep my specs clean as possible and thought factories would be a great place to keep this configuration...

**Is there a fabrication library that would let me do this?**

Just some more experimentation:

```
> "WHY ARE YOU NOT A STRING".to_f
=> 0.0
```

Okay, so somewhere, in rails or in factorygirl, `to_f` is being called on my beloved string. Where? And how do I stop it?

Comment: If you want to do input param validation, you should do it in a controller test. At the model level, rails typecasts input on assignment. E.g. `product.new.price = 'somestring' ` will result in 0.0 for price. In other words, in your model, you can never have a string value for a float column.

Comment: This has nothing to do with factory girl. Your database column is defined as float, so ActiveRecord automatically cast it . If you want to get the original value assigned to given attribute, use `price_before_type_cast`. Another point: your factories should always generate valid models - if you want to use them for validation testing purpose, change values manually in the test.

Comment: @BroiSatse Why does ActiveRecord have anything to  do with a factory being built/created? I thought the idea was you can use factories in mocks, completely isolated from the model layer. Maybe rspec's mock_model is better than fixtures/factories...

Comment: @Starrkers - FactoryGirl is to generate models, not to stub them. If you want to test one model in complete isolation from other models, then use factory girl to generate it and stub all its associations. (or only those you are expecting to be used in test). Could you update your question with the actual problem you're having, i.e. what you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

With `fabrication` you need to use `attributes_for` to generate a hash representation of your object. It will bypass the `ActiveRecord` model entirely so nothing should be coerced.

`Fabricate.attributes_for(:string_product)`